# Weird~Apache can not find the actually existing "bash" to execute my cgi file~

Tags: apache, cgi

May be it's too easy for you to answer.
My problem is about cgi and apache web server.
Make it simple, I have a html "form.html" containing a form in it. To access it, typing "127.0.0.1/form.html" in browser.
After clicking "submit" in this html file, it is supposed to adress to "127.0.0.1\cgi-bin\cginame.cgi", the content of "cginame.cgi" is as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $REQUEST_METHOD="GET" ]
then
data=$QUERY_STRING
else
data='cat'
fi
java mortcal $data
```

"mortcal" is a java program calculating and return a HTML page containing results to user.
I'm using apache 2.2 and ubuntu 10.04.
The problem is when I click the "submit" button in "form.html", I got these in error log:

```
[Sat Sep 24 15:00:20 2011] [error] (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/mortcgi.cgi' failed
[Sat Sep 24 15:00:20 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: mortcgi.cgi
```

I know it's because apache can not find "/bin/bash" to execute the cgi file. But I do have "/bin/bash".
It's so weird. Please help me out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please change your CGI script to a simple "echo Hello world". Let's narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked my configuration files. They are ok. So I kept searching on the web and finally I saw this:

"If you've copied over the script from a Windows machine, you may be being tripped up by ^M at end of line. You can use cat -v /usr/lib/cgi-bin/printenv.pl | head -1 to verify that there isn't a ^M at the end of the line. "

I did copy my cgi file from windows! I forgot to mention it because I did not think it's a big deal.

Now I have removed the ^M by typing this" :%s/^V^M//g in vi. This problem is resolved. Thanks very much for your answer, Mr.Harrison and Dark Falcon, Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

To execute CGI scripts, you need to configure Apache to allow this, and your script has to follow the HTTP protocol by sending back data in the right format, and right permissions, and on and on and on.

Here's a great tutorial with an example: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html

... however, I need to say: running a java program from within a shell script via Apache is a bad idea, in general.  Each request loads the java runtime engine (JRE), runs the program, then unloads it.  There are issues with environment, file ownership and so on -- all of this is why there are application servers like tomcat for java.  So if you're just trying something, that's fine.  If you're thinking this is a good way to get something done in a professional production environment, I would reconsider.

Comment: I checked my configuration files. They are ok. So I kept searching on the web and finally I saw this:"If you've copied over the script from a Windows machine, you may be being tripped up by ^M at end of line.

You can use cat -v /usr/lib/cgi-bin/printenv.pl | head -1 to verify that there isn't a ^M at the end of the line.
"

I did copy my cgi file from windows! I forgot to mention it because I did not think it's a big deal.
Now I have removed the ^M by typing this"

:%s/^V^M//g

in vi. This problem is resolved.

Thanks very much for your answer, Mr.Harrison and Dark Falcon, Thank you all.

Comment: @YanjinDing, add this as a new answer, and accept it. This way, others who find your question will know how you resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, this seems like a poor way to do things, but:

1. Do the script file permissions allow execution for the web server user?
2. Are you using any security framework such as selinux which would apply additional restrictions?